# Arrange 20 SKSpriteNode in a circle

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have an array with the names of 20 SKSpriteNode objects. I want to arrange those nodes in a circle like this:

[image: Circular arrangement of 12 nodes]

Just with 20 instead of 12 nodes. It should also be more accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can be solved with a little bit of math. A circle around the point (x0,y0) with the radius r can be written as

```
x = x0 + r * sin(t)
y = y0 + r * cos(t)
```

with t going from 0 to 2π. If you plug in any number in this range into those equations you get the coordinates of a single point on that circle. To get equal distances you just divide the whole range of 2π by the number of items you want to arrange (20) and use that as the t step between your objects. Then you can use the parametric circle equation to calculate the coordinates and set the position property of your sprite nodes.